# React Redux this.props is empty?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use the **react-boilerplate** structure for my project.
I have a container LoginForm that authenticates a user and stores the response from an API in state.
I would like to access this response from another container NavHeader which is the header and it should render those information.

The `this.props` in NavHeader is undefined. Can someone point me towards where I've gone wrong here.

> UPDATE: I tried to move the reducer and actions over to App (root) container, still no luck. Clearly I'm not doing something right, and I can't figure that out. any help would be greatly appreciated!

## UserLoginForm container

### index.js

```
export class UserLoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

onLoginSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.props.dispatch(authorize(email, password));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <HeroBannerStyle>
          <form>
                <InputField name="email" />
                <InputField type="password" />
                <Button onClick={this.onLoginSubmit}/>
          </form>
      </HeroBannerStyle>
    );}}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  userLoginForm: makeSelectUserLoginForm(),
}); 
==> This essentially does this: state.get('userLoginForm', initialState);

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps);
const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'userLoginForm', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'userLoginForm', saga });

export default compose(withReducer,withSaga,withConnect(UserLoginForm);
```

### actions.js

```
export function authSuccess(payload) {
  return {
    type: AUTH_SUCCESS, payload: {user: payload},
  };
}
```

### reducer.js

```
export const authorize = (email, password) => ({
  type: AUTH_REQUEST,
  payload: {email, password},
});
export const initialState = fromJS({
  user: null
});

const userLoginFormReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case AUTH_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: payload.data,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userLoginFormReducer;
```

### saga.js

```
function* fetchUserReqSaga({ payload: { email, password } }) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(fetchUser, { email, password });
    yield put({ type: AUTH_SUCCESS, payload: response });
} catch (error) {}
}

function fetchUser({ email, password }) {
  return usersAPI.post('/login', {email, password,});
}
```

---

## Container NavHeader

### index.js

```
class NavHeader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }       
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log('this.props..', this.props);//THIS IS UNDEFINED
      }

      render() {
        return (
              <div>{this.props.user}</div> // THIS IS EMPTY
        );      
}}
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      console.log(state); //THIS DOES NOT HAVE 'userLoginForm'
      return {
        user: state.get('userLoginForm')
      }
    };

    const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps);
    const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'navHeader', reducer });
    const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'navHeader', saga });
    export default compose(withReducer,withSaga,withConnect)(NavHeader);
```

Comment: too much code, please narrow down your problem and post relevant code from where anyone can understand.

Comment: @Justcode I've just updated the post to more readable code. I wanted to post all these here to ensure I was doing this right, and if this could be a reason to why I wasnt able to receive the props. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Hi, is anybody able to provide what i'm missing here. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The components and (rootReducer, rootSaga) are connected to the store through which all the actions and props are coming. You can debug in browser to see how the data is going.

Here is an official documentation. It is easy and quite short, but crucial to understand all this reducer,action, props stuff. There is also a small codepen snippet to see how it works.

[Redux docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/tree/master/docs)

[Short redux example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo)

Also here is the extract from similar project. Added some more lines from breaking points.

UPD:

It takes data from rootReducer that is connected to the store. combineReducers is called when store is initialised and connect all reducers:

```
export interface RootState {
    books: BooksState;
    authors: AuthorsState;
}

const rootReducer: Reducer<RootState> = combineReducers<RootState>({  
    authors: authorReducer,
    books: booksReducer

})
export default rootReducer;
```

After reducer returned the payload(data) it is taken by selector:

```
export const getData = (state: RootState) => state.books.data
```

and it is used in mapStateToProps, I used **connect** to call high order func and collect data from store and create container. Compose is not a redux and if you use it you must check the order of your middlwares (compose(m1, m2, m3...) from right to left):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  books: getData(state), 
  pagination: getPagination(state),
  loading: getLoadingStatus(state),
  error: getError(state),

})

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadBooks, searchBook, removeBook, addBook,  editBook, sortBook, 
    })(FilterableBooksTable);
```

Then it comes to the 'clever' component:

```
export interface BooksTableProps {
    readonly books: Array<Book>;
    loadBooks: (pagination: Pagination) => object; 
}

export interface BookFormProps {
    addBook: (name: string, author: string, cost: number, genre: string) => object;
}

type FilterableBooksTableProps = BooksTableProps & BookFormProps;

export default class FilterableBooksTable extends React.Component<FilterableBooksTableProps> {

render() {
  const {
    books,
    loadBooks,
    addBook,                   
  } = this.props

  return (        
      <div>
          <Row>
            <Col span={4}>
              <BookForm
                addBook={addBook}                    
                >
            </Col>
            <Col span={16}>
              <BookTable        
                books={books}
                loadBooks={loadBooks}            
              />
            </Col>                
          </Row>
      </div>        
  )
  }
```

And finally the data reaches the 'stupid' component:

```
render() {
   const {
       books                
   } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>           
      <Table          
        dataSource={books}          
        ...
      />
    </div>                
  )
}
```

I don't know what is your store config, so I'll add mine with all sagas, reducers connected to it:

```
import { Store, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer, { RootState } from '@redux/rootReducer';
import rootSaga from '@redux/sagas';

export default function configureStore(initialState?: RootState): Store<RootState> {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

  const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({});

  const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
  );

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState!,
    enhancer,
  );

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('@redux/rootReducer', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('@redux/rootReducer').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

  return store;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RamanHaivaronski. I pass the email and password back to `AUTH_REQUEST`, and if successful, goes to `AUTH_SUCCESS`. That sets the state in the reducer. `user: payload.data,` Still unsure what's missing.

Comment: @alienzee I hope that's not very large explanation for you with a little bit of ts though